# How to add your own syntax to Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, oniguruma

I want to add my own syntax (language) to Sublime Text 2. I already know how to include it to the syntax list so my only problem now is the syntax highlighting. But first I want to understand the [Oniguruma](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt) language used for matching the words I want to highlight so I can make things on my own.

Here's my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>fileTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>xmp</string>
    </array>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>XMP</string>
    <key>patterns</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>match</key>
            <string>??????????????????????????????????????????????</string>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>source.keyword.xmp</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>scopeName</key>
    <string>source.xmp</string>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>750d3b02-a1bc-4b09-a794-1b78c54a4e21</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And just like the other programming languages (e.g HTML or XML), instead of using `<>` (in HTML) I'll use `[]` and also the `/` for closing the statement. So  basically I'll just replace those `<>` to `[]` but how can I translate it to **Oniguruma** (regex)?

---

Here's what I want it to be

```
<key>patterns</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>match</key>
        <string>[SIZE=""][/SIZE]</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>code.size.xmp</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>match</key>
        <string>[BOLD][/BOLD]</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>code.bold.xmp</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
replace: /<(\/)?(.*?)>/g
     to: [\1\2]
```

https://regex101.com/r/zC8mG5/8

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I can't understand what you're pointing to...

Perhaps I did understand the substitution `[\1\2]` that you're saying. Based on the explanation, it'll only match any character except newlines (please correct me if I'm wrong) but I want to match the exact word and the symbols `[size=""]` not any random characters. And I also want an auto listing function...

Like, if I'm going to type `[` it'll automatically list those only possible **exact** words included to my language, just like the other default programming languages that Sublime Text already has. (e.g Java)

Yes, not only the codes that I wanted to be translated to regex but also the syntax-highlighting (coloring) and the automatic listing function I'm talking about...

Here's just an examples of my codes

```
[SIZE=""]texts here[/SIZE]          Will change the font size. (Usage [SIZE="integer"])
[BOLD]texts here[/BOLD]             Will change the font weight.
[CENTER]texts here[/CENTER]         Will align texts to center.
[ITALIC]texts here[/ITALIC]         ...
[UNDERLINE]texts here[/UNDERLINE]   ...
[STRIKE]texts here[/STRIKE]         ...
....
```

Thanks for the answer tho :)